# What is the difference between spatial analogy and perceptual analogy in Natural mapping

Tags: usability, layout, design, terminology

I am reading *Norman's* book, **The design of everyday things** where I came upto the **natural mapping** part. There, he defined 3 kinds of natural mapping.

```
1- Spatial
2- Cultural
3- Perceptual
```

Now, In **spatial**, he says, `a control can be used to move the object up and down.`
And In **perceptual**, he gives example of `car seat controls to move the car seat`. Now I am confused what is the actual difference between these two? Isn't moving the object up and down or moving the seat with controls are same. I know, I am missing something, so if anyone know, please clear me about this problem and help me to understand it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spatial controls move objects. Perceptual controls move the controller.

For example, a jet pilot uses perceptual controls to move himself and the plane. However, a drone pilot uses spatial controls to move only the drone: he remains stationary.

Said another way, think of it like the rectangle-square relation: all perceptual controls are also spatial, but not all spatial controls are perceptual. If a control modifies the world perception of the controller, it is perceptual (as well as spatial).

Comment: This makes sense to me. So you mean, all perceptual mapping are spatial as well, right? in a sense that object is moving, but when a person who is controlling that object also moves or affected by the action, then it is perceptual. Did i understand it right? thank you for your answer.

Comment: @WaqarAhmed Yes, you understand correctly!

Comment: well, I always understood something completely different to this answer, guess I'll need to re-check the book again :D

Comment: @Devin .. then please reconfirm it to me as well..i have an exam on this tuesday...:p

Comment: @Devin The [2013 edition](http://cc.droolcup.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/The-Design-of-Everyday-Things-Revised-and-Expanded-Edition.pdf) doesn't even include these distinctions. My answer is based on the 1988 edition, which to a degree conflated feedback and placement. In the modern text, both my examples would be spatial and the "perception" part would be descrived in terms of feedback and affordance.

Comment: @bishop, tbh  I don't remember if this distinction I have is  by Norman or other source, so you're most likely correct. I didn't comment to say you were wrong, but to say I was mistaken in what I thought